# VBScript split string into array, use array element to alter value of HTML input box

Tags: html, arrays, vbscript

I have a small batch file that generates a text file that looks like the following:

```
deviceimei=123456789874563
serialnumber=XXXXXXXXXXXX
partnumber=XXXXXLL/A
brand=XXX
manuf=XXX
```

I'm attempting to use vbscript (In an HTA file) to loop through this text file and fill HTML input boxes based on the value.

Here is my vbscript:

```
<script language="VBScript">

    Sub gatherInfo
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("info.txt")

        Do Until f.AtEndOfStream

          splitString = Split(f.ReadLine, "=", -1)
          splitString(0).Value = splitString(1)

        Loop
    End Sub

</script>
```

This should loop through the text file, break each string by the equals sign, use the 1st element (before the equals sign) as the ID of the input box that needs to be changed, and set the value to the 2nd element (after the equals sign)

As it stands, this does not work. I get an error:

> Object required: 'splitString(...)'

How can I achieve what I am trying to achieve?

My HTML:

```
<p><button onclick="vbscript:gatherInfo">gather</button></p>
<p>Brand: <input id="brand" type="text"/></p>
<p>Manufacturer: <input id="manuf" type="text"/></p>

<p>Serial Number: <input id="serialnumber" type="text"/></p>
<p>IMEI: <input id="deviceimei" type="text"/></p>
<p>Part Number: <input id="partnumber" type="text"/></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a collection indexed by the keys of your key-value-pairs:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>alpha</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oAlpha"/>
    <script language="VBScript">
Sub gatherInfo()
  s = "brand=XXX"
  a = Split(s, "=")
  document.all(a(0)).value = a(1)
End Sub
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <p><button onclick="gatherInfo">gather</button></p>
    <p>Brand: <input id="brand" type="text"/></p>
   </body>
</html>
```